# Error: Method 'toUpperCase' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null

Tags: dart

what should i repair? it's error.

`characterList[index]['real_name'].toUpperCase()`

How can fix the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add null check like this

```
characterList[index]['real_name']!.toUpperCase()
```

or change String? to String

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that it can't be `null` but just have a nullable `?`, just cast it like this:

```
(characterList[index]['real_name'] as String).toUpperCase()
```